# MediaWiki : How to add image (icon) in a sidebar for each menu if the menu is in Cyrillic?

Tags: css, mediawiki, sidebar, cyrillic

I have Skin:Metrolook a drop-down menu with a submenu which looks like this:

[image]

Thus, I have several various menus with submenus in the sitebar.
I want to add an individual icon before each menu.
I can't assign classes orID s for each menu (as in the example [here](https://wikirouge.net/MediaWiki:Vector.css)) in my MediaWiki:Metrolook.css because the menu is written in Russian language , and CSS perceives only English letters, but not Cyrillic. All my attempts to determine the ID comes down to a set of characters of this type:
p-.D0.A6.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.8B:-list
So CSS it does not perceive such symbols and also does not perceive Cyrillic.
I tried to assign to in my MediaWiki:Sidebar

```
 <div id="cv">*Пример</div>
```

and write in css this combination :
#p-cv :before { content: url(/img/white_tulip.png); } and .n-cv:before { content: url(/img/white_tulip.png); } and .cv:before { content: url(/img/white_tulip.png); }and #cv:before { content: url(/img/white_tulip.png); } but it doesn't work.However, page  MediaWiki:Sidebar does not perceive the encoding in the menu on the page, as I understand it.
However, I noticed that if write in css

```
#p-navigation li a:before, 
#n-Info-sur-WikiRouge a:before  { content: url(/img/white_tulip.png); }
```

then the icon appears in the navigation of the service menus from below
At the same time, this menu is also on Cyrillic- but this menu is embedded in Mediawiki as standart.But this is just an observation.
Please say how can I add icons in my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the sidebar menu, this code should work in `MediaWiki:Metrolook.css` (ID and URL from my own wiki):

```css
#n-Техподдержка a:before {
    content: url(/files/thumb/3/33/Nuvola_apps_bookcase.png/51px-Nuvola_apps_bookcase.png);
}
```

The corresponding line of *MediaWiki:Sidebar* is:

```
** Project:Техническая поддержка|Техподдержка
```

If the necessary id is encoded with full stops, the full stop should be escaped with a backslash in CSS selector:

```css
ul#p-\.D0\.A1\.D0\.BE\.D0\.B7\.D0\.B8\.D0\.B4\.D0\.B0\.D0\.BD\.D0\.B8\.D0\.B5-list:before {
    content: url(/files/thumb/3/33/Nuvola_apps_bookcase.png/51px-Nuvola_apps_bookcase.png);
}
```

Both tested in *MediaWiki* and *MetroLook* 1.35; in newer versions of *MetroLook* the structure of the sidebar menu, and therefore, the selector, can change. But, anyway, CSS can work with Cyrillic identifiers.

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение, работает ! :)